# Bengali data input in R

Tags: r

[UPDATED WITH SOME DATA AND TRIAL CODE]

I have some numeric in Bengali unicode format. Want to develop some graphs with the data. But R reads the data as "character" instead of "numeric". How do I make R to read the data as "Numeric". Thanks.

My data table looks like following:

```
"সংখ্যা"    "বছর"
৩৪,৭০৮    ২০১১
৩২,৮১০    ২০১২
৩২,৮৯৪    ২০১৪
```

I have converted both the columns to numeric with as.numeric function:

```
mb$`“সংখ্যা”` <- as.numeric(mb$`“সংখ্যা”`)
mb$`“বছর”` <- as.numeric(mb$`“বছর”`)
```

The class was converted with warning:

```
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

Then I tried to plot a bar graph:

```
ggplot(mb, aes("বছর", "সংখ্যা"))+
geom_bar(stat = "identity", width=0.3)
```

It resulted in following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVkxN.png)

---

followed Rohit's code, then tried to draw bar graph:

```
ggplot(mb, aes(x="বছর", y="সংখ্যা"))+
geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

It didn't work, image link:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBCfS.png)

Then drew a plot with data in English, it worked fine:

```
ggplot(mbe, aes(x=year, y=number))+
geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

plot image:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7oDf.png)

Any observation/suggestion?

Comment: Kindly Ready Stack-overflow Guidelines and add what effort u made yet in code and where exactly you getting the problem.

Comment: Thanks. Did not know the norms/rules of the platform.

Comment: @polash, I've edited my answer with your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to convert the numbers to the english/latin equivalent. You can do this using the `stringi` library. Then you can change them to numbers using `as.numeric()`

```
n <- '১০৫'
library(purrr)
library(stringi)
n %>% stri_trans_general('Bengali-Latin') %>%as.numeric()
# [1] 105
```

Edit: for the data you've provided, you can do something like this:

```r
    mb
    # সংখ্যা  বছর
    # 1 ৩৪,৭০৮ ২০১১
    # 2 ৩২,৮১০ ২০১২
    # 3 ৩২,৮৯৪ ২০১৪
    library(dplyr)
    library(stringi)
    mb <- mb %>%
      mutate_all(function(x){ # mutate_all will apply the function to all columns of mb
        x %>%
          stri_trans_general('Bengali-Latin') %>% # convert to latin charset
          gsub(pattern = ',',replacement = '')%>% # Commas need to be removed
          as.numeric()
      })
    # সংখ্যা  বছর
    # 1 34708 2011
    # 2 32810 2012
    # 3 32894 2014
```

Edit: For the plot, your column names have Bengali and quotes so they need to be enclosed in backticks:

```
ggplot(mb,aes(`"বছর"`,`"সংখ্যা"`))+
  geom_col()
```

Comment: @Rhoit, thanks for the answer. Would you please elaborate how do I convert numbers in columns in a data file? Here is my data:

সংখ্যা  বছর
৩৪,৭০৮  ২০১১
৩২,২০৩  ২০১২
২৬,৩৩১  ২০১৩
৩২,৮৯৪  ২০১৪
৪৬,৭৬৪  ২০১৫
৫৩,৭৩৮  ২০১৬
৭৫,২৫১  ২০১৭
১,০৪,০৬৪ ২০১৮

Comment: Please don't put data in comments. Edit your post to show your data and the code yiou have tried.

Comment: Thanks. Did not know norms/rules of the platform. Have updated the question with some data and trial code. Please take a look. Thanks.

Comment: I tried your conversion code. Please see the details in my question.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! And one more question: is it correct that drawing plot with Bengali data without converting it into English (Latin) is not possible in R?

Comment: I personally don't know of a way to change the language for showing numbers in a plot. utf/unicode characters can be used in strings so you can look into changing the axis labels and ticks in the plot